# Time Indexing issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code

```
import datetime
#import numpy as np
import jacks_toolbox.getHistoricalData as dt


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Config
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rolling_time = 15
num_days = 20

Start = "2016-09-27 00:00:00"
End = "2016-10-14 23:00:00"

settleTimeStr = "2016-10-14 14:00:00"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start execution
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get a window of data from MySQL and plot it
startTime  = datetime.datetime.strptime(Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
endTime    = datetime.datetime.strptime(End, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
settleTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(settleTimeStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print "Start time: " + startTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "End time: " + endTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print "Settle time: " + settleTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data = dt.getHistoricalDataByTime(startTime, endTime, 5)
settles = dt.getHistoricalDataByTime(startTime, settleTime, 5)

print settles[::1425]
```

I am trying to index it so that it prints the thetime every 24 hours from my starting time, but currently it is printing the following:

```
Start time: 2016-09-27 00:00:00
End time: 2016-10-14 23:00:00
Settle time: 2016-10-14 14:00:00
Inst                     7_year        UBZ6
2016-09-27 00:00:00   99.735491  183.839583
2016-09-28 00:00:00   99.906250  185.593750
2016-09-29 00:00:00   99.714375  184.936422
2016-09-30 00:00:00  100.012908  186.308594
2016-10-03 00:00:00   99.596467  184.013021
2016-10-04 00:00:00   99.450893  183.697917
2016-10-05 00:01:00   99.109375  181.457386
2016-10-06 00:01:00   98.953804  180.645833
2016-10-07 00:01:00   98.761837  180.049107
2016-10-10 00:01:00         NaN  179.682292
2016-10-11 00:31:00   98.584375  178.619318
2016-10-12 00:31:00   98.501563  178.125000
2016-10-13 00:31:00   98.799342  179.251042
2016-10-14 00:31:00   98.687500  178.328125
```

For some reason this is adding one minute, then 30 minutes to the times I am trying to index it on, and I am not sure why this is. Initially I started with 1440 since that is 24*60 but noticed that it was off by 15 minutes for the first group of times so I then switched to 1425 and this is what I got. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be far more efficient to sample your times at the database level rather than trying to slice the full dump. If you have any missing rows or they're not quite sorted it would explain the jumps.

Comment: What's `jacks_toolbox`? Where is `minTicks` defined? Why do you import `numpy` and then apparently don't use it? There's not enough information here. I'm kind of surprised Mark seems to be following what you're doing, because I sure have no idea.

Comment: @JohnY I'm not following it either, just making a simple suggestion based on the little that's shown here. The last line in particular is easy to understand, although it wouldn't lead to the exact output shown.

Comment: Sorry about that jacks_toolbox is a package that somebody I know created and is used to pull this data. I had numpy being used in a part of the code that I didn't include, and I accidentally left minTicks in.

Comment: Saying that `jacks_toolbox` is "some package" doesn't help. Either there is a bug in `jacks_toolbox` or there is missing data. There is no way of knowing, given only what you have provided in your question. The point of my question was: if this package is available on GitHub or something, then you could share a link to it and we could look at it. Then we **might** be able to tell if the problem is a bug in the package.